# Android Material Design templates

Tags: android, material-design

I am new to Android development and i am wondering about one thing. I want to create a simple list like descriped here: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-specs

I cannot believe, that i have to implement it all by myself. Every ImageView, TextView with all their paddings and textsizes and so on. Is there something i overlooked? Is there a simple way like ready-to-use layouts?

If i want to use Material Design in a Web project, i could go to https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/list and create a list by just copy and paste the sourcecode. Does something like that exist for Android too?

Comment: Look into listviews with custom adapters

Comment: He didn't ask how to populate list, he rather search a ready-made templates.

Comment: That's right, RediOne.. If someone knows where to get it, please give me a hint..

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to implement the view for a single item and android uses it as template. You can use a build-in list item only if you are showing String values.
Android developers sometimes also have to be UI developers.

You can check this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Have in mind that Material design in Android is slightly **different** than Material design for Web.